# How to add new list item with Image in custom list through sharepoint web service?

Tags: c#, image, web-services, sharepoint-2010

I am developing asp.net web application. I am accessing sharepoint list data through lists.asmx web service. Similary I am adding data in sharepoint list through lists.asmx. My code to add new list item is as follows

```
public void InsertDataInClientList(Client clientObj)
        {
            PBSWebApplication.LocalHostServiceReference.ListsSoapClient proxy = Utility.GetLocalProxy();

            try
            {

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlElement batch = doc.CreateElement("Batch");

                batch.InnerXml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>"
                    + "<Field Name='FirstName'>" + clientObj.FirstNameOfIndividual + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Last_x0020_Name'>" + clientObj.LastNameOfIndividual + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='PATIENT_x0020_DOB'>" + clientObj.DateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Age'>" + clientObj.Age + "</Field>"    
                    + "<Field Name='Gender'>" + clientObj.Gender + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Preferred_x0020_By'>" + clientObj.ReferredBy + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x002f_Caregiver_x0020_Fir'>" + clientObj.Parent1FirstName + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x002f_Caregiver_x0020_Las'>" + clientObj.Parent1LastName + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_1_x0020_Street_x002'>" + clientObj.Parent1StreetAddress + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_1_x0020_City'>" + clientObj.Parent1City + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_1_x0020_State'>" + clientObj.Parent1State + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_1_x0020_Zip'>" + clientObj.Parent1Zip + "</Field>"                    
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_1_x0020_Home_x0020_'>" + clientObj.Parent1HomePhone + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_1_x0020_Work_x0020_'>" + clientObj.Parent1WorkPhone + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_1_x0020_Mobile_x002'>" + clientObj.Parent1MobilePhone + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_1_x0020_Mobile_x002'>" + clientObj.Parent1MobilePhone + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_1_x0020_Email'>" + clientObj.Parent1Email + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Marital_x0020_Status'>" + clientObj.Parent1MaritalStatus + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_2_x002f_Caregiver_x'>" + clientObj.Parent2FirstName + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_2_x002f_Caregiver_x0'>" + clientObj.Parent2LastName + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_2_x0020_Street_x002'>" + clientObj.Parent2StreetAddress + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_2_x0020_City'>" + clientObj.Parent2City + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_2_x0020_State'>" + clientObj.Parent2State + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_2_x0020_Zip'>" + clientObj.Parent2Zip + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_2_x0020_Home_x0020_'>" + clientObj.Parent2HomePhone + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_2_x0020_Work_x0020_'>" + clientObj.Parent2WorkPhone + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_2_x0020_Mobile_x002'>" + clientObj.Parent2MobilePhone + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_2_x0020_Email'>" + clientObj.Parent2Email + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Parent_x0020_2_x0020_Marital_x00'>" + clientObj.Parent2MaritalStatus + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Insurance_x0020_Company_x0020_Na'>" + clientObj.InsuranceCompanyName + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='INSURED'>" + clientObj.InsuredCardHoldersName + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='INSURED_x0020_DOB'>" + clientObj.InsuredCardHoldersDateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Insured_x0020_SSN'>" + clientObj.InsuredSSN + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Member_x0020_Number'>" + clientObj.MemberNumber + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='GROUP_x0020__x0023_'>" + clientObj.GroupNumber + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Physician'>" + clientObj.Physician + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Physician_x0020_Phone_x0020_Numb'>" + clientObj.PhysicianPhoneNumber + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Medicaid_x0020_Id'>" + clientObj.MedicaidNumber + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Need_x0020_additional_x0020_help'>" + clientObj.NeedAdditionalHelp + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Interested_x0020_in_x0020_Speech'>" + clientObj.InterestedInSpeechAndLanguageServices + "</Field>"
                    + "<Field Name='Interested_x0020_in_x0020_Occupa'>" + clientObj.InterestedInOccupationalTherapy + "</Field>"
                    + "</Method>";

                XElement xElement = Utility.ToXElement(batch);

                proxy.UpdateListItems("Clients", xElement);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utility.ShowErrorMessage(ex);
            }

        }
```

The above code working fine. I am able to add new list item. In the above code 'Clients' list is custom list. Now in 'Clients' list I have one more field with column name Image. It is of type 'Hyperlink or Image'. I can manually add image in this column by providing the web address. But I want to add this image through code behind. I have byte array of image. I also have source url. I want to add the image with the above field values. I want to add image for particualr list item. Means I want t update the list item by adding image into it. How should I do that. Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Comment: You might try posting this over at SharePoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

When I create a file using SharePoint's web services I always end up using the Copy Service.  If you are adding attachments to a list item you may be able to get around this.  If not, below is an example that should get you moving in the right direction:

```
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[InputFile.PostedFile.InputStream.Length];
    InputFile.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    string soapStr =
        @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
              <soap:Body>
                <CopyIntoItems xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"">
                  <SourceUrl>http://devint/a/ceo/PublishingImages/FridayMemoHeader1.png</SourceUrl>
                  <DestinationUrls>
                    <string>http://sp-pubdev:88/Resources/Images/testFile.png</string>
                  </DestinationUrls>
                  <Fields>
                  </Fields>
                  <Stream>{1}</Stream>
                </CopyIntoItems>
              </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>";

    System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url);
    req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItems\"");
    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    req.Accept = "text/xml";
    req.Method = "POST";
    //req.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    req.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myUserName", "myPassword", "Domain");

    using (System.IO.Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        soapStr = string.Format(soapStr, "testFile.png", Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter stmw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stm))
        {
            stmw.Write(soapStr);
        }
    }
```

You will probably be most interested in the first two lines, which are just loading a file into a byte array, and this line:

```
soapStr = string.Format(soapStr, "testFile.png", Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
```

Where that byte array is converted to a base64 string and inserted into the SOAP request.  Good luck!